# В чём разница в смысле между «С чего это ты ...» и «Отчего ты ...»?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> **С чего это** ты вдруг стал обо мне заботиться? А?
>
> {по сравнению с}: **Отчего** ты вдруг стал обо мне заботиться? А?

Чем отличается по смыслу «с чего» от «отчего» в это предложении? Слова вроде похожи, но полагаю, различие всё равно ощущается. Возможно, используют «с чего», когда удивились, что что-то случилось неожиданным образом?

Интересно, кстати, почему подчеркивающая частица «это», похоже, не подходит к использованию с «отчего»?

> **Отчего это** ты вдруг стал обо мне заботиться? А?

Comment: «Отчего это» вполне допустимо в разговорной речи.

Answer (score 4):

The first version sounds **unfriendly** (*это* emphasizes it) and expresses suspicion of hidden motives. And it's rather a rhetorical question.

> Why on earth would you start taking care of me all of a sudden?

The second one is *more neutral*, but the included **вдруг** also expresses some suspicion or surprise.

> Why (for what reason) did you start taking care of me all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

Alex_ander is right, but the first version also could mean a surprise, like:

> Wow. What has changed? Why would you start taking care of me?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Alex_ander that the first version sounds much more offensive. But it also depends on how you say it and the context.

I would say

> С чего это вдруг ты стал обо мне заботиться?!

Even more offensive might be

> С [rude word here] ли ты стал обо мне заботиться?!

If I want to sound polite I would ask

> Почему ты стал обо мне заботиться?

Разница в том, на чем ты делаешь акцент в предложении, какие эмоции ты хочешь выразить.

1. Грубая форма `с чего`, которая звучит резко, может быть даже как эвфемизм. `Отчего` или `Почему` звучат не так резко. Хотя смысл один и тот же.
2. Акцент на слове `вдруг` - `это вдруг`, чтобы подчеркнуть, что ты никогда до этого обо мне не заботился, но вдруг ты обо мне вспомнил. Подозрительно.

I intentionally explained this in Russian because I hope this will help you to learn the language. Also I am not linguist and this all is how I understand things.